# Calculate percent change over time on an unsorted dataframe using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

```
    Name        Date ID  Amount
0   Faye  2019-12-31  A       2
1   Faye  2020-03-01  A       3
2   Faye  2019-09-30  A       1
3   Mike  2019-09-30  A       7
4   Mike  2019-12-31  A       7
5   Faye  2019-09-30  B      10
6   Mike  2019-12-31  B      12
7   Faye  2019-12-31  B       8
8   Faye  2019-06-30  B       5
9   Mike  2019-09-30  B      10
10  Faye  2019-09-30  C       5
11  Mike  2018-03-31  D       5
```

And for each `Name`, `Date`, `ID`, group I want to calculate the % change of `Amount` from the previous `Date` (if there is one), by adding it as a new column (`% Change`). And if it didn't exist previously, add something like `New`, so that the `new_df` looks like:

```
    Name        Date ID  Amount % Change
0   Faye  2019-12-31  A       2        1
1   Faye  2020-03-01  A       3       .5
2   Faye  2019-09-30  A       1      New
3   Mike  2019-09-30  A       7      New
4   Mike  2019-12-31  A       7      NaN
5   Faye  2019-09-30  B      10       .5
6   Mike  2019-12-31  B      12       .2
7   Faye  2019-12-31  B       8      -.2
8   Faye  2019-06-30  B       5      New
9   Mike  2019-09-30  B      10      New
10  Faye  2019-09-30  C       5      New
11  Mike  2018-03-31  D       5      New
```

I tried `df['% Change'] = (df.groupby(['Name', 'Date', 'ID'])['Amount'].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1)` but it returns all `NaN`. Maybe this is because the data isn't sorted? So how do I achieve this without a sorted dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().pct_change` with sorting:

```
df['% Change']= (df.sort_values('Date')
                   .groupby(['Name','ID'])
                   .Amount.pct_change()
                   .fillna('New')
                )
```

Output:

```
    Name        Date ID  Amount % Change
0   Faye  2019-12-31  A       2        1
1   Faye  2020-03-01  A       3      0.5
2   Faye  2019-09-30  A       1      New
3   Mike  2019-09-30  A       7      New
4   Mike  2019-12-31  A       7        0
5   Faye  2019-09-30  B      10        1
6   Mike  2019-12-31  B      12      0.2
7   Faye  2019-12-31  B       8     -0.2
8   Faye  2019-06-30  B       5      New
9   Mike  2019-09-30  B      10      New
10  Faye  2019-09-30  C       5      New
11  Mike  2018-03-31  D       5      New
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not sort and then do the calculation? That would work:

```
t = df.sort_values(["Name", "ID", "Date"])
t["change"] = t.Amount.pct_change()
t.loc[(t.shift()["Name"] != t.Name) |(t.shift()["ID"] != t.ID), "change"] = None
t
```

This would result in: (you can ignore the `inx` column):

```
    inx Name    Date    ID  Amount  change
2   2   Faye    2019-09-30  A   1   NaN
0   0   Faye    2019-12-31  A   2   1.0
1   1   Faye    2020-03-01  A   3   0.5
8   8   Faye    2019-06-30  B   5   NaN
5   5   Faye    2019-09-30  B   10  1.0
7   7   Faye    2019-12-31  B   8   -0.2
10  10  Faye    2019-09-30  C   5   NaN
3   3   Mike    2019-09-30  A   7   NaN
4   4   Mike    2019-12-31  A   7   0.0
9   9   Mike    2019-09-30  B   10  NaN
6   6   Mike    2019-12-31  B   12  0.2
11  11  Mike    2018-03-31  D   5   NaN
```

Comment: Clean way! +1, if OP wants the 'new' there, then he can always use `t = t.fillna('new')`

Comment: This works but I think @Quang Hoang's solution is a little cleaner